# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), how to fix it?

Tags: php, html, syntax

i was make a login script, and it's the index :

```
<?php
        session_start() 
        if(isset($_POST['username'])&&!empty($_POST['username'])){
        header("location:login.php");
    }
    echo "selamat datang ".$_SESSION['username'];
    ?>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

when i try it, it show me :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

anyone know?

Comment: Start looking at the `if`, then look what happens *before* it.

Comment: Its just simple **typo**. You forgot _semicolon_ in your `session_start()`. You need to analyze carefully you code...

Answer (score 0):

Space is improper and use `;` after `session_start`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
    header("location:login.php");
}
echo "selamat datang ".$_SESSION['username'];
?>
<br/><br/><br/>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

MISSING **;** AFTER session_start

```
<?php
        session_start(); 
        if(isset($_POST['username'])&&!empty($_POST['username'])){
        header("location:login.php");
    }
    echo "selamat datang ".$_SESSION['username'];
    ?>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
        session_start(); //miss semicolon
        if(isset($_POST['username'])&&!empty($_POST['username'])){
        header("location:login.php");
    }
    echo "selamat datang ".$_SESSION['username'];
    ?>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```